# Does this vacuum motor use DC or AC power?

Tags: motor, vacuum

If this is not the right SE for this, which would be a better one?

This is a listing on Aliexpress. I gave the motor DC power at 12, 24, and 32vdc and did not limit the amps. The motor gave one shake each time but otherwise did not run. The listing does not say if this is an AC or DC motor, but then I noticed there are 3 wires on this. 
[image]

[Current listing is here](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32996199235.html?spm=a2g0s.12269583.0.0.38c833f8J6tbMd).

Thank you.

EDIT: I just realized I don't know how to tell which driver board will work with this motor though I did learn about why these need drivers.

Answer (score 4):

It's a brushless DC motor and you need a brushless drive for it.  You can't power it by DC alone, it needs an electronic drive circuit.

From the seller:

> Features:
>   Imported two-turbine blade brushless fan motor, dose not have driven maschine, need to operate by brushless drive. It has 24V brushless 6000Pa electric test suction, and the actual fan is tested with brushless electric test 12V current 1.3A speed 18000 rpm, 24V voltage test current 3.2A speed 31000 rpm.

Example of BLDC (brushless)
[image]
Schematic from Electro-Tech-Online.com

(From [here](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN1913.pdf), page 16.)

Comment: * What is a brushless driver? Is that a PCB board? Do you have an example that would work with this motor? 
* Why do I need a brushless driver for this when many other motors I just have to apply power? I have never used any driver board for any motors I use.

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to learn as I go. This will be an opportunity to learn about motors which need a driver circuit.

Comment: Brushless uses electronics (yes, a driver PCB) instead of mechanical sliding contacts which add friction and wear out. So for more complex electronics you get higher performance, lower noise, and longer life (less wear) especially at 31000 rpm!

Comment: If you're going to steal [someone else's diagram](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN1913.pdf) (page 16) instead of drawing your own, you need to [provide attribution](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Otherwise, this is plagiarism, and we do not allow it here.

Comment: Dave - will provide attribution next time, just needed a quick example.

Answer (score 2):

Learn from your lack of due diligence to find key words like "brushless" = DC to AC with commutation using Hall Sensor (Yellow).

Other motors may commutate by sensing current changes with position using 2 wires. 
eg.
[image]
$12 20V-24V Violent Brushless Turbine air blower Fan 80000rpm 200W for Vacuum Cleaner

(Image source: [AliExpress](https://www.aliexpress.com/i/33006190081.html))

All Motors are rotating AC currents.  But how this is done with Brushless motor design can be complex using FET switches to prvent shoothru and reduce noise,while increasing current and torque with RPM rather the the opposite as in starter motors , yet avoid the hot arcing brushes and armatures normally used with brush type AC motors